# Get short weekdays names for Portuguese language in Android

Tags: android

I need to return the short version of the weekdays names using [getShortWeekdays()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormatSymbols#getShortWeekdays()) in Android. I tested with different device language settings. Although it seems to be working with various language settings, unfortunately when the selected language is Portuguese (Portugal), it returns the full day names. Any advice?

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
String[] dayNames = symbols.getShortWeekdays();
```

Output if language is English (United States):

```
["", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
```

Output if language is Portuguese (Brasil):

```
["", "dom.", "seg.", "ter.", "qua.", "qui.", "sex.", "sáb."]
```

Output if language is Portuguese (Portugal):

```
["", "domingo", "segunda", "terça", "quarta", "quinta", "sexta", "sábado"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At first, I wondered if using a different package for the method's class would produce different results, but it didn't.

```java
final java.util.Locale pt_BR = new java.util.Locale("pt", "BR");
android.icu.text.DateFormatSymbols symbolsPtBr1 = new android.icu.text.DateFormatSymbols(pt_BR);
String[] dayNamesBtBr1 = symbolsPtBr1.getShortWeekdays();
Log.e("LOCALE_ANDROID", String.format("%s(%s): (android.icu.text): %s", pt_BR.getDisplayVariant(), pt_BR.getDisplayName(), Arrays.toString(dayNamesBtBr1)));

java.text.DateFormatSymbols symbolsPtBr2 = new java.text.DateFormatSymbols(pt_BR);
String[] dayNamesBtBr2 = symbolsPtBr2.getShortWeekdays();
Log.e("LOCALE_ANDROID", String.format("%s(%s): (java.text): %s", pt_BR.getDisplayVariant(), pt_BR.getDisplayName(), Arrays.toString(dayNamesBtBr2)));

final java.util.Locale pt_PT = new java.util.Locale("pt", "PT");
android.icu.text.DateFormatSymbols symbolsPtPt1 = new android.icu.text.DateFormatSymbols(pt_PT);
String[] dayNamesBtPt1 = symbolsPtPt1.getShortWeekdays();
Log.e("LOCALE_ANDROID", String.format("%s(%s): (android.icu.text): %s", pt_PT.getDisplayVariant(), pt_PT.getDisplayName(), Arrays.toString(dayNamesBtPt1)));

java.text.DateFormatSymbols symbolsPtPt2 = new java.text.DateFormatSymbols(pt_PT);
String[] dayNamesBtPt2 = symbolsPtPt2.getShortWeekdays();
Log.e("LOCALE_ANDROID", String.format("%s(%s): (java.text): %s", pt_PT.getDisplayVariant(), pt_PT.getDisplayName(), Arrays.toString(dayNamesBtPt2)));
```

The log output (tested on Android 7.0):

```
LOCALE_ANDROID: (Portuguese (Brazil)): (android.icu.text): [, Dom, Seg, Ter, Qua, Qui, Sex, Sáb]
LOCALE_ANDROID: (Portuguese (Brazil)): (java.text): [, Dom, Seg, Ter, Qua, Qui, Sex, Sáb]
LOCALE_ANDROID: (Portuguese (Portugal)): (android.icu.text): [, domingo, segunda, terça, quarta, quinta, sexta, sábado]
LOCALE_ANDROID: (Portuguese (Portugal)): (java.text): [, domingo, segunda, terça, quarta, quinta, sexta, sábado]
```

Therefore, you can just truncate each weekday to a two- or three-letter symbol length with ***substring(0, len)*** and capitalize it with ***StringUtils.capitalize()*** method as this is the approach used for the issue in OsmAnd https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand/issues/5115